# Add a class to a parent element based on image alt tag?

Tags: jquery

Check a few of the other post and found the code I needed, but doesn't do exactly what I need it to do.

I want to add a class to the parent element based on the alt tag of an image.

So from this:

```
<div class="img-wrap">
   <div class="img-icon">
      <a href="">
         <img alt="home" />
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class="img-wrap home">
   <div class="img-icon">
      <a href="">
         <img alt="home" />
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here's the code I'm using:

```
$('img').each(function() {
$(this).parent().addClass( $(this).attr('alt') );
});
```

While this adds the needed class, it adds it to the "a"... however I want it to add to the #img-wrap. How can I do this?

Comment: `ID` should be unique.. You should not duplicate ID like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID should be unique.. You should not duplicate ID like that. Try changing it to class `class="img-wrap"` and check out the below code.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="img-wrap">
   <div class="img-icon">
      <a href="">
         <img alt="home" />
      </a>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Code:**

```
$('img').each(function () {
   $(this).closest('.img-wrap').addClass(this.alt);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img').each(function() {
$(this).parents('#img-wrap').addClass( $(this).attr('alt') );
});
```

OR

```
$('img').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass( $(this).attr('alt') );
    });
//to make it more obvious why it is not selecting the #img-wrap <div>
```

And yes, #IDs should only be used once, use a class instead if this repeats itself

Answer (score 0):

use .closest() to select the parent element you want
http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.closest()`

Note that **Id** in the HTML page is supposed to be unique.. Try giving the div  a **class** instead of an **ID**

```
    $('img').each(function() {
       $(this).closest('.img-wrap').addClass( $(this).attr('alt') );
    });


<div class="img-wrap">
  <div class="img-icon">
     <a href="">
       <img alt="home" />
     </a>
  </div>
```